# files inside root directory not accessible mod_rewrite PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The file structure looks like this

- root
- root/x
- root/x/y.php
- root/index.php

.htaccess code

```
RewriteRule (.*) /x/$1 [L]
```

What the htaccess file does is to remove the folder name (x) from the url so accessing y.php = http://localhost/y.php instead of http://localhost/x/y.php . This works but my problem now is the index.php shows something like this:

```
Index of /x

Parent Directory
y.php
```

I can't access the index.php. I believe the x became the root folder.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure that `index.php` shows that, not your server?

Comment: the server shows that. Inside the index.php I echoed a Hello world but it doesn't show. I tried to create a index.php inside the x with the same echo "Hello world"; and it showed! So I believe the x folder became the root.

Comment: But isn't that what you wanted? I mean for what else has the rewrite rule written if not that?

Comment: The only thing I want is to remove folder names in the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you shouldn't allow index displays like this on a public server ... on your localhost it may be okay, but still, you can disable it in your .htaccess by adding this:

```
Options -Indexes
```

To address your question, you should probably add the following conditions before your rewrite rule so that the rule won't apply to any files or directories that actually exist on disk:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

This won't fix the issue you have because the .htaccess is redirecting to a non-existant **/x/index.php** file ... this is why it's showing the index listing for the **/x** directory

Comment: I have now a existing /x/index.php and that became the default file instead of root/index.php

Comment: Right ... that's what the last sentence of my answer means.

Comment: The reason I have this mod_rewrite thing is to remove folder names in the URL. And I made it wrong, thus altering the default folder/file.